# Declaring variable final v. delayed instantiation

Tags: java, design-patterns, final

**Delayed instantiation**

```
public class Foo{
    private NotSoExpensiveObject o;

    public NotSoExpensiveObject getNSEObject(){
        if(o == null){
            o = new NotSoExpensiveObject();
        }
        return o;
    }
}
```

**Declaring final**

```
public class Foo{
    private final NotSoExpensiveObject o;

    public Foo(){
        o = new NotSoExpensiveObject();
    }
}
```

Does declaring `NotSoExpensiveObject` final have any advantage over delaying its instantiation? Or is this purely situational? Also, is there a way to delay instantiation, and keep the `final` modifier?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> Does declaring NotSoExpensiveObject
>   final have any advantage over delaying
>   its instantiation? Or is this purely
>   situational? Als

`final` will make it constant , unmodifiable(i.e. `CONST` equivalent of C, once you assign it you can't change the value ). It has nothing to do with lazy initilization

> is there a way to delay instantiation, and keep the final modifier

Probably the place where you seen this code wants not to the value to be non-modifiable and so the `final`

Comment: you might be careful on the unmodifiable point there. It could be interpided to mean a mutable object somehow becomes unmodifiable.

Comment: @Andrew Thanks , added more info

Answer (score 1):

Final is only a **compile time** restriction and as such finals members must be initialized inline when they are declared or in the constructor. The "delayed" final is nice when different constructors need to initialize the final member differently.

Comment: what do you mean by _"delayed" final_? I can't declare `NotSoExpensiveObject` final when I delay its instantiation, although it is essentially guaranteed to be initialized once by each instance of `Foo`. I guess what I'm really curious about is if there's any performance benefits to giving variables the `final` modifier...probably not.

Comment: By delayed I mean assign the value to the final member in a constructor rather than a member. There is performance difference in the different uses of final but there may be a slight performance boost if final is used at all.

Comment: I though this was is true only for local variables - and that you can check Modifier.isFinal(myField). I remember reading that declaring class variables final has effects how they are initialized, which can affect synchronization?

Answer (score 1):

Delayed Instantiation may not be thread safe, unless you synchronize.

Answer (score 1):

Is your Foo class used from different threads? If yes, you need to add synchronization to the lazy initialization solution. You would not have to do this if you used the 'final' variant. In that case the JVM guarantees that the reference to NoSoExpensiveObject is visible to other threads.

There's also no way to keep the final modifier and still use lazy initialization. Final members need to be initialized immediately or through a constructor.